# Azure Databricks: trying to run Spline for capturing Spark lineage?

Tags: azure-databricks, spline-data-lineage-tracker

I am trying to set up [Spline](https://absaoss.github.io/spline/#tldr) in Azure Databricks but facing this issue, any help regarding this?

```
<console>:6: error: identifier expected but double literal found.
     --packages za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark:spark-3.0-spline-agent-bundle_2.12:0.6.1 \
```

I have installed the corresponding Spark agent in the cluster by downloading from here - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark/spark-3.0-spline-agent-bundle_2.12/0.6.1

[image: Notebook]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to execute a shell command as a Scala code snippet.

Please follow this guide explaining how to setup and use Spline on the Databricks - https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline-getting-started/tree/main/spline-on-databricks